# Help interpreting this result based on conditioning on gender -Contigency Tables

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, contingency-tables

[image]

The problem i'm having is how to interpret the results I got. For part a) I got that the abortion laws are independent of generation where I used a $\chi^2$ test. For part b) I got that the the age is conditionally independent of opinion when we condition on the sex of the respondent. That is if we split the table into two among the women and men then we get that the age groups among men and women are independent of their opinion. That is age does not impact opinion conditioned on gender I think. I need to go one step further and explain this in simpler terms, but I am confused. I know that part a and b are definitely related. Any help would be great thanks.